# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity(TextView is null)

Tags: android, custom-font

I am trying to add custom fonts in my android app.

**LoginActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        Button signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
        TextView username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/smartwatch.ttf");
        username.setTypeface(custom_font);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent loginOnlyIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LoginOnlyActivity.class);
                startActivity(loginOnlyIntent);
            }
        });


        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent signUpIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Signup.class);
                startActivity(signUpIntent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have added `assests` folder in the `src/main` folder too.In the `assests` folder is `fonts` folder in which I have font file `smartwatch.tff`

I have checked almost every answer available on SO but nothing worked so far for me.

**update:**
After using Debugger, I found that

```
TextView username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
```

returns null and hence the NPE.

Adding layout file :

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="155.0dip"
            android:paddingTop="200.0dip"
            android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
            android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/UserName"
                android:id="@+id/username"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_phone"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:hint="  "/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Please help me why textview username is null

Comment: Please edit with the full logcat... Not just the exception reason

Comment: Is this XML you are showing `activity_login.xml`? If not, that explains why it is null

Comment: are you inflating the correct layout file in your `onCreate` method of Activity? I don't see any other reason as to why `TextView` may be null...

Comment: @cricket_007 yes it is `activity_login.xml`

Comment: Please show the full XML. Where are the two buttons?

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me.
[image]

---

In LinearLayout you provided missing buttons, but I think you have added them in your project.  In addition, I have error because you have omitted the XML namespace

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

into Linear Layout.

Try to Invalidate and restart project, It 's strange the null pointer problem on TextView, You've done all right, unless the problem lies elsewhere.

Make sure you have created the Assets folder doing:
Right click on "app" folder, new --> Folder --> Assets Folder

Comment: The namespace is missing because what is shown is only a sample of the XML layout